# Undefined name 'context' after adding showDialog

Tags: flutter, dart

I often struggle with this issue and I am hoping can help explain it to me as well as proffer a solution if necessary. The issue is with the showDialog that I have added.

I have read through other similar questions but the solutions provided are very confusing for me.

**Below is an excerpt of my code**

```
class AuthenticationController extends GetxController {
  final loginKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final registerKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final forgotPasswordKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late TextEditingController loginEmailController,
      loginPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  late TextEditingController nameController,
      registerEmailController,
      registerPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController forgotPasswordEmailController = TextEditingController();

  String name = '';
  String email = '';
  String password = '';

  
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    loginEmailController = TextEditingController();
    loginPasswordController = TextEditingController();
    nameController = TextEditingController();
    registerEmailController = TextEditingController();
    registerPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();

    loginEmailController.dispose();
    loginPasswordController.dispose();

    nameController.dispose();
    registerEmailController.dispose();
    registerPasswordController.dispose();
  }

  String? validateName(String value) {
    if (value.length <= 3) {
      return kShortNameError;
    }
    return null;
  }

  String? validateEmail(String value) {
    if (!GetUtils.isEmail((value))) {
      return kInvalidEmailError;
    }
    return null;
  }

  String? validatePassword(String value) {
    if (value.length <= 6) {
      return kShortPassError;
    }
    return null;
  }

  

  Future<void> loginUser() async {
    try {
      
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) => Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
      if (loginKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        loginKey.currentState!.save();
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: loginEmailController.text.trim(),
          password: loginPasswordController.text.trim(),
        );
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
    } finally {
      
    }
  }

  Future<void> registerUser() async {
    try {
      
      if (registerKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        registerKey.currentState!.save();
        Get.offAll(BottomNavigation());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    } finally {
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is of context. And in flutter context is really important without it, it won't know where to render your circular progress indicator. There can be many approaches to solve this problem so I am open to suggestions via other people and ain't listing them all for my sake.

Since you are working with GetX, It provides an overlay context for such use cases. So you need to call dialog like this

```
Future<void> loginUser() async {
    try {
      
      //using Get.overlayContext
      showDialog(
        context: Get.overlayContext,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) => Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
      if (loginKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        loginKey.currentState!.save();
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: loginEmailController.text.trim(),
          password: loginPasswordController.text.trim(),
        );
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
    } finally {
      
    }
  }
```

To close the dialog you can use bellow line wherever you find needful:

```
 Navigator.of(Get.overlayContext).pop();
```

Comment: If my solution helped please mark it as correct so it would be easy for others.

Comment: It did not solve the problem. I am getting another error saying "The argument type 'BuildContext?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'."

Comment: can you try `Get.overlayContext!` use an exclamation mark.

Comment: I did try it and it didn't work so I had to use another approach altogether. I appreciate your effort in helping me resolve the issue. @Krish